# hoverintent not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, hover, hoverintent

I have something like this:

```
$('li',$dcVerticalmenuObj).hoverIntent(config);


var config = {

    interval: 100, 
    over: megaOver, 
    timeout: 0, 
    out: megaOut 
};


function megaOver(){
    $container.css(containerPosition).show();
}
```

but the hover function not working in IE 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know what happen..my jquery is outdated i guess..once i replace it with the latest version http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js thn everything working fine